# Forgot screen lock pin and airplane mode on

Tags: lock-screens, screen, sim-unlocking

Hi i have a Samsung Galaxy A30S.
I added a screen lock pin code and can't remember it.
The airplane mode is activated and I cannot turn it off, cause it's asking for pin number.
I don't want to do a hard or factory reset since I have very important memories of photos and phone numbers in it. Please Help.

Comment: There is no way to bypass lock screen PIN.

Answer (score 0):

Its understandable. Everyone automatically assumes Stolen, but sometimes we legitimately just forget after setting an uncommon password or PIN.

Some programs to look into that will help, but are most likely not free by normal channels are Dr. Fone, 4ukey, UnlockGo, PassFab, FonePaw, DroidKit, and try doing a search for "Samsung FRP and PIN Unlock Programs." Samsung is probably the Most common Android Brand, so there are a lot of programs. There are also a lot of "Developer Unlock Programs (All-In-One Tools)" to be found in searching. Only testing will define whether or not they will work with your model (Dr. Fone Is BRANDED Wondershare, one of the better options). Some programs like "Chimera" can get pricey.

You can also search through [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) for tricks on your specific device model.

I know a bypass trick, don't know if it will work with your Samsung model, and unfortunately it would normally require a factory reset unless your Google Assistant is active. I don't know, I've only ever tried after a factory reset, and from the beginning of setting the phone up. I'm also unsure if Assistant works in Airplane mode.

RECOVERY Mode:
Turn Phone off. Then press and hold Volume+, and Press and hold Power until logo screen comes on. Then release, and Recovery Mode with the Hard Factory Reset Option should appear.

(After Factory reset from Recovery Mode)
Normally I would tap on the Vision Settings from startup and activate 'Talk-Back.'

Then exit Talk-Back Menu. Next, swipe on the screen in a reverse L (swipe right and then up) to activate Talk-Back Voice Command. Then say, 'Open Google Assistant.' Google Assistant should open.

(Start Here if you already have access to Google Assistant or if the above worked)
With Assistant activated say 'Open Settings.'
(If the phone is still requiring a PIN, an external PC program is most likely required)
[If the above worked from either starting point, you should now have at least access to all settings not protected by a PIN or FRP Lock, and should be able to disarm Airplane Mode in theory]

The above tricks worked on my OnePlus Nord N200 5G - Android 12. I have yet to test it on my Samsung Galaxy A14 5G - Android 13.

Additionally, I can reach the Home Screen from Settings by going to Home Screen Settings and changing the Home Screen Layout. I don't know why but it grant's me Home Screen access behind a PIN and FRP lock.

Worth a shot. Goodluck, I hope something that I've offered helps in some way.

Comment: No-one has mentioned stolen. So why mention it, unless you are a bot. Just curious.

Comment: Why is it an issue to you that I mentioned it? Trolling? Just curious.

Comment: Folks can say there's no bypass all day, but there are bypass tricks. Technology is not 100% fool-proof. Finding bypass methods is literally how we improve security features in new models.

Comment: For instance. On Mediatek phones there's a Shell Tool called MTKClient. Runs in conjunction with Git, Python, and Platform-Tools (adb and fastboot). Designed specifically for Mediatek phones. MTKClient has several FRP and PIN lock bypass codes meant for entire removal of owner identification traces, reseting to original state. The issue is saving the files. This will cause a phone wipe no matter what. I have around 15 different Samsung Programs designed to do the Same thing. All depends on the Model phone and how current it's release. The more current the model, the better security features.

Comment: Adb is only useful if you activated debug Mode before getting locked out of the device. Otherwise Adb is useless as it is the operation of the android shell from within. Fastboot is designed for Flashing Firmware after Unlocking OEM/Flashing, which requires the Bootloader to be unlocked. Which require Debug Mode and for the carrier/SIM to be Unlocked by a code given by the phone carrier directly. After a year of service....

Comment: I've gone through this with my OnePlus Nord N200 5G. I straight forgot the information. In my search to free my phone, I've found tons of unlock methods.. for other phones. Figured out the bypass tricks I originally posted, but have yet to find a legit unlock for OnePlus. Weaknesses in OS design sure, but no legit unlock full access method with the Google FRP in place. Even after bypass I can't get into Dev Mode with it locked behind a PIN.

Comment: Every time I asked how to unlock a smartphone, I've been met with typically no response and outright refusal to give me aid. I've called MetroPCS, but carriers cannot aid in Phone PIN retrieval. Only SIM codes, etc. This question is what sent me down the Android programming road to begin with.The very last option being, send the phone in to the original manufacturer (in my case OnePlus) and have them flash the phone. Costs a fee. But there are always options.

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing the pin of android would be a huge security issue so no methods are known and even if there where OEM would patch it.

Your best chance of keeping your data is by using fastboot or adb... But for that you need developer settings with oem unlocked and usb debbuging. You could pull all your precious data and then factory reset the phone.

If you did not enabled the dev options you'll have to reset the phone unless you exploit a security flaw in your OS but that shouldn't happpen.